# Compact $L^\infty$ spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

I try to understand when $L^\infty(X;Y)$ is compact. Is the following statement true?

If $X\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $Y\subset\mathbb{R}$ are both compact, then $L^\infty(X;Y)$ is compact.

Comment: What's $L^\infty(X;Y)$ to you?

Comment: Isn't $L^\infty$ a normed vector space? If so it is never compact. Or maybe: what is $L^\infty$ to you?

Comment: Oh. You are right. The first statement does not make any sense, since it is a vektor space.

Comment: For the second statement: $L^\infty(X;Y):=\{f\in L^\infty(X)\mid f(x)\in Y \text{for almost every }x\in X\}$ is a subset of $L^\infty(X)$. So this set could be compact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Measurable subsets of $\sigma$-finite non-atomic measure spaces have $\sigma$-finite non-atomic induced measure, and therefore either $X$ is a null set or $X$ may be partitioned into a countably infinite union of disjoint measurable subsets of positive measure.

If $X$ is a null set or $\# Y\le 1$, then $\#L^\infty(X;Y)\le 1$ and it's therefore compact.

If $\lambda(X)>0$, $X=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i$ with the $E_i$ as above and $u,v\in Y$ with $u\ne v$, then consider $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}u&\text{if }x\in E_n\\ v&\text{if }x\notin E_n\end{cases}$$

And notice that $d_\infty(f_n,f_m)=\lvert u-v\rvert$ for all $m\ne n$. Therefore $L^\infty(X;Y)$ isn't a compact subset of $L^\infty(X)$.